# Chatbot sem acesso à internet

Tags: machine-learning, chatbot

Boa noite!

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, existe a possibilidade de criar Chatbot usando o Watson Assistant ou as tecnologias Microsoft para ser acessado de um server local sem acesso à internet?

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta curta, improvável.

Resposta detalhada:

As tecnologias de chatbot como o IBM Watson e o MS Luis usam modelos de NLP(natural language processing) que são treinados e hospedados na nuvem, justamente para abstrair essa dificuldade do cliente e facilitar o treinamento desses algoritmos(que demandam muito poder computacional).

Contudo, já vi que alguns provedores de nuvem tem opções de instalar toda a sua "nuvem" dentro de um data center on-premises, como isso acho que exista a possibilidade de ter um chatbot sem acesso à internet, provido por uma nuvem local, dentro da intranet de sua empresa.